# Run-time error storing pointer character from strtok after multiple calls

Tags: c

I'm making a program that inputs a string and converts it to pig-latin. I found after multiple calls to strtok, I would get a run-time error after trying to store the pointer value in another string.

When I try and store the character the pointer is pointing to after one call, it works fine, but after I call the function a second time, I get a run-time error when it is trying to store the character.

```
// Inputs a string with a maximum of 100 characters
// tokenizes it and converts it to pig latin in a new string
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 101

unsigned int ModifiedStringSize(char inputString[SIZE]);
void ManipulateString(char inputString[SIZE], char *outputStringPtr);

int main(void)
{
    // inputString is where
    // string entered by user
    // is stored
    char inputString[SIZE];
    
    // fgets reads up to 100
    // characters into inputString
    fgets(inputString, SIZE, stdin);
    
    // call function
    // ModifiedStringSize to calculate indexes
    // required to store pig-latin
    // converted string
    unsigned int indexes = ModifiedStringSize(inputString);
    
    // allocate indexes found by
    // ModifiedStringSize
    char outputString[indexes];
    
    // call function
    // convertString to convert
    // string to pig-latin
    // to output
    ManipulateString(inputString, outputString);
}

unsigned int ModifiedStringSize(char inputString[SIZE])
{
    // variable stores how many indexes
    // the modified pig-latin string will
    // require
    unsigned int indexes;
    
    // begin calculating indexes at non-null characters
    // in inputString plus one
    for (indexes = 0; inputString[indexes] != '\0'; indexes++) {
    }
    
    // begin tokenizing string
    char *tokenPtr = strtok(inputString, " ");
    
    // for loop increments indexes by two
    // every time token is found because
    // every token in pig-latin is two
    // characters longer
    for (; tokenPtr != NULL; indexes += 2) {
        tokenPtr = strtok(NULL, " "); // get next token
    }
    
    // return required indexes
    // for converted string
    return indexes;
}

void ManipulateString(char inputString[SIZE], char *outputStringPtr)
{
    char *tokenPtr = strtok(inputString, " ");
    
    tokenPtr = strtok(NULL, " ");

    *outputStringPtr = *tokenPtr;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that `strtok` *modifies* the buffer.

The caller to your functions would have to pass a *temporary* buffer that has been copied from the original *before* each call.

In other words, the call to `ModifiedStringSize` trashes `inputString` so that when you call `ManipulateString`, the updated value for `inputString` is [effectively] garbage.

The usual here is to parse a buffer only *once* and retain a `char **` array that is built up from the `strtok` loop.

---

**UPDATE:**

> Sorry, I'm still learning C and I'm not really that good with pointers. How exactly do I implement this?

There are basically *two* ways to do this:

1. Caller passes a pointer to a fixed size `char **` array that the subfunction fills in with tokens [for a *given* line]
2. The subfunction uses `malloc/realloc` to create and maintain a dynamically increasing list of tokens. It *returns* a pointer to that array.

Option (1) is easier/simpler and is suitable for line-at-a-time processing. That is, all necessary processing can be done without having to combine multiple lines of input (e.g. this is probably suitable for your use case).

Option (2) is used if we have to read an *entire* multiline file and store *all* lines before doing any processing. *Or*, we can *not* predict how many tokens we'll need before attempting to parse. It is the *caller's* responsibility to call `free` on the array elements and the array pointer itself.

Note that I had to refactor your code a bit.

---

Here's the first method:

```
// Inputs a string with a maximum of 100 characters
// tokenizes it and converts it to pig latin in a new string
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define SIZE        1000
#define DELIMS      " \t\n"

void piglatin(char *pig,const char *inp);
void pigall(char **toklist);

// parse_string -- parse a line into tokens
// RETURNS: actual count
int
parse_string(char *inputString,char **toklist,int tokmax)
{
    char *bp = inputString;
    char *cp;
    int tokcount = 0;

    // allow space for NULL terminator
    --tokmax;

    while (1) {
        cp = strtok(bp,DELIMS);
        bp = NULL;

        if (cp == NULL)
            break;

        if (tokcount >= tokmax)
            break;

        toklist[tokcount++] = cp;
    }

    // add end of list
    toklist[tokcount] = NULL;

    return tokcount;
}

int
main(void)
{
    // inputString is where
    // string entered by user
    // is stored
    char inputString[SIZE];

    char pig[SIZE];

    // some simple tests
    piglatin(pig,"pig");
    piglatin(pig,"smile");
    piglatin(pig,"omelet");

    // fgets reads up to 100
    // characters into inputString
    printf("Enter phrase: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    fgets(inputString, SIZE, stdin);

    // define the worst case number of tokens that are possible (e.g. each
    // token is one char)
    char *toklist[((SIZE + 1) / 2) + 1];

    // parse the string into tokens
    int tokcount = parse_string(inputString,toklist,
        sizeof(toklist) / sizeof(toklist[0]));
    printf("tokcount is %d\n",tokcount);

    // translate all tokens into pig latin
    pigall(toklist);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here's the second method:

```
// Inputs a string with a maximum of 100 characters
// tokenizes it and converts it to pig latin in a new string
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define SIZE        1000
#define DELIMS      " \t\n"

void piglatin(char *pig,const char *inp);
void pigall(char **toklist);

// parse_file -- parse all tokens in a file
// RETURNS: token list
char **
parse_file(FILE *xfsrc,size_t *tokc)
{
    char *bp;
    char *cp;
    char buf[SIZE];
    size_t tokmax = 0;
    size_t tokcount = 0;
    char **toklist = NULL;

    while (1) {
        // get next line
        cp = fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),xfsrc);
        if (cp == NULL)
            break;

        bp = buf;
        while (1) {
            // get next token on line
            cp = strtok(bp,DELIMS);
            bp = NULL;
            if (cp == NULL)
                break;
            printf("DEBUG: '%s'\n",cp);

            // NOTE: using tokmax reduces the number of realloc calls
            if (tokcount >= tokmax) {
                tokmax += 100;
                toklist = realloc(toklist,sizeof(*toklist) * (tokmax + 1));
            }

            // NOTE: we _must_ use strdup to prevent the first and subsequent
            // lines from being jumbled together in the _same_ buffer
            toklist[tokcount++] = strdup(cp);

            // add null token to end of list (just like argv)
            toklist[tokcount] = NULL;
        }
    }

    // trim list to amount actually used
    if (toklist != NULL)
        toklist = realloc(toklist,sizeof(*toklist) * (tokcount + 1));

    // return number of tokens to caller
    *tokc = tokcount;

    return toklist;
}

// tokfree -- free the token list
char **
tokfree(char **toklist)
{

    for (char **tok = toklist;  *tok != NULL;  ++tok)
        free(*tok);

    free(toklist);

    toklist = NULL;

    return toklist;
}

int
main(void)
{

    // some simple tests
    char pig[SIZE];
    piglatin(pig,"pig");
    piglatin(pig,"smile");
    piglatin(pig,"omelet");

    // parse entire file
    size_t tokcount;
    char **toklist = parse_file(stdin,&tokcount);

    // translate all tokens into pig latin
    pigall(toklist);

    // free the list
    toklist = tokfree(toklist);

    return 0;
}
```

---

**Spoiler Alert:** Here's the pig latin code I used to test the above with:

```
// piglatin.c -- convert words to pit latin

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int
isvowel(int chr)
{

    chr = (unsigned char) chr;
    chr = tolower(chr);
    return (strchr("aeiou",chr) != NULL);
}

void
piglatin(char *pig,const char *inp)
{
    const char *rhs;
    char *lhs;
    char pre[100];

    *pig = 0;
    rhs = inp;

    do {
        if (isvowel(*rhs)) {
            strcat(pig,rhs);
            strcat(pig,"yay");
            break;
        }

        lhs = pre;
        for (;  *rhs != 0;  ++rhs) {
            if (isvowel(*rhs))
                break;
            *lhs++ = *rhs;
        }
        *lhs = 0;

        strcat(pig,rhs);
        strcat(pig,pre);
        strcat(pig,"ay");
    } while (0);

    printf("%s --> %s\n",inp,pig);
}

void
pigall(char **toklist)
{
    char pig[1000];

    for (char **tokp = toklist;  *tokp != NULL;  ++tokp)
        piglatin(pig,*tokp);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm still learning C and I'm not really that good with pointers. How exactly do I implement this?