# Way to call function Pig_Latin_Converter correctly?

Tags: c, function, user-defined-functions

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

void Pig_Latin_Converter(char *a);

int main() {
    
    char password[50];
    
    printf("Please input password: ");
    int passw = 0;
    do {
        password[passw] = getch();
        if(password[passw] != '\r') {
            printf("*");
        }
        passw++;
    }
    while(password[passw - 1] != '\r');
    password[passw - 1] = '\0';

    Pig_Latin_Converter(password);
    
    return 0;
}

void Pig_Latin_Converter (char *a) {
    int v = 0, c = 0, pos = 0,sv = 0, ch;
    strlwr(a);

    if(a[0]=='a'|| a[0]=='e'|| a[0]=='i'|| a[0]=='o'|| a[0]=='u'){
        ++sv;
        printf("\n\nPig Latin Equivalent: %syay", *a);
    }
    else
    {
        ++c;
        for (int i = 0; a[i] != '\0'; ++i)
        {
            if (a[i] == 'a' || a[i] == 'e' || a[i] == 'i' ||
                a[i] == 'o' || a[i] == 'u') {
                ++v;
                pos=i;
                break;}
        }
    }

    if(c==1 && v==1)
    {   
        printf("\n\n");
        printf("Pig Latin Equivalent: ");
        for(int i=pos; i<strlen(*a); i++) {
            printf("%c", a[i]);
        }
        for(int i=0;i<pos;i++)
        {
            printf("%cay", a[i]);
        }
    }
    else if(c==1 && sv==0)
    {   
        printf("\n\n");
        printf("Pig Latin Equivalent: %syay", *a);
    }
}
```

Hello, I'm a beginner in using user-defined functions used in C programming. This program is tasked to input masked password then translate it to Pig Latin. But, I kept on coming up with errors on this. Is there a way to solve this? I have a huge gut feel that the problem is only inside the function Pig Latin.

Comment: Please _edit_ your question and detail the errors you are getting specifically. (e.g.) What input produces what output.

Comment: The compiler should give you a warning about `printf("\n\nPig Latin Equivalent: %syay", *a);`.  It will tell you what is wrong.  (There are probably many other issues, but this one jumped out at me.)  If you do not get a warning, you should figure out how to turn up the diagnostics on your compiler.  If it does give warnings, you should read and understand them.

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65710780/run-time-error-storing-pointer-character-from-strtok-after-multiple-calls/65710939#65710939 for some working pig latin code